# How to pull Meta Description into Search Results

Tags: kentico

I am trying to display the meta descriptions (instead of the page's content) below the page titles on my search results page.

Here is what currently is in the transformation. I am pretty sure I have to change out "Content" for something, just not sure what.

```
<p<%#TextHelper.LimitLength(HTMLHelper.StripTags(RemoveDynamicControls(GetSearchedContent(DataHelper.GetNotEmpty(Eval("Content", false), ""))), false, ""), 280, "...")%></p>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This worked great! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In v9, meta fields are by default indexed by the Smart Search. The only thing you need to do is to pull the information out by calling:

```
GetSearchValue("DocumentPageDescription")
GetSearchValue("DocumentPageTitle")
GetSearchValue("DocumentPageKeyWords")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using 'General' indexer type (index pages f.e.), you can check fields that you want as 'Searchable' in the Search fields tab, on newly created indexer.